# to line up label and select in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web site to fill out a form and I use a Bootstrap template, but in I do not know how to separate my select from the labels.

NOW

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54oji.jpg)

```html
<form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" action="form_validationtwo.php" method="POST" novalidate>
                    <span class="section">¿QUE?</span>
                      <div class="row">
                        <label for="sel1">Debemos declarar que infraestructura utilizamos para realizar las actividades del proceso, aquí nos centramos en equipos, instalaciones y los puestos de trabajo responsables de dicha infraestructura:</label>
                        <input hidden="¿QUE?" name="ID_QUE" value="1">  
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="que" value="que"></textarea>
                         <br>
                         <div class="col-xs-17">
                            <label for="sel1">Posible Riesgo: Es esa vulnerabilidad o amenaza a que ocurra un evento y sus efectos sean negativos y que alguien o algo puedan verse afectados por él</label>
                             <input hidden="¿QUE?" name="ID_QUE" value="1">  
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="que" value="que"></textarea>
                         </div>
                         <br>
                         <div class="col-xs-17"> 
                                 <label for="sel1">Evauación Criticidad</label>
                                 <select class="form-inline" >
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>    
                                   </div>
                     
                                  <div class="col-xs-17">
                                 <label for="sel1">Evauación Ocurrencia</label>
                                 <select class="form-inline" >
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>    
                                  </div>
                     
                                 
                                       <br>
                        <div class="col-xs-17">
                            <label for="sel1">Plan de Acción: es un plan que prioriza las iniciativas más importantes para cumplir con ciertos objetivos y metas</label>
                            <input hidden="¿QUE?" name="ID_QUE" value="1">  
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="que" value="que"></textarea>
                        </div>

                          </div>
```

how do I need it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCaNY.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your labels and selects inside a row div first. Then separate them with col divs:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="sel1">Evauación Criticidad</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <select class="form-inline" >
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
        </select>    
    </div>
</div>
```